# Why does set_position fail in this code

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, glade, gtk2

When I build this same ui in Glade (the program) the resulting code is flawless, when I code it by hand everything works except one thing, the set_position(670) is ignored and the resulting window comes up at about 1" square on my screen.

My goal is to get the left hand pane to instanciate at 670 px wide.  I am not concerned about locking the width.

I have tried placing the call to set_position(670):

- where it is shown now
- 2 lines further down
- After the `self.top.show_all()`
- Just before the `self.top.show_all()`
- Just after call to `pack1`

Searching google has lead to no usefull results, and there are no useful answers here that I have found so far.

The pyGtk site indicates that the call can be placed almost anywhere.
The gtk site lists no restrictions.
Most things I have found seem to indicate it is due to the resize/shrink attributes of one of the other widgets, but after numerous attempts at altering the values of everything in the left pane, I am still at a loss.  (Note that value changes were tried one or two at a time.)

```
import gtk
import gobject


class Source(gobject.GObject):

    def _emit_signal(self, button, value):
        self.emit('choice_changed', self, value)

    def __init__(self):
        self.__gobject_init__()
        # packing treee
        # top
        #   main
        #     inst_align
        #       inst_window
        #         instructions
        #     opt_align
        #       opt_buttons
        #         opt_0 (through opt_5)
        #         doit_box
        #           doit
        self.top = gtk.Alignment(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        self.main = gtk.HPaned()
        self.main.set_position(670)
        self.top.add(self.main)
        # Build left side components
        self.inst_align = gtk.Alignment(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        self.inst_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow(None, None)
        self.inst_window.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        self.instructions = gtk.TextView(None)
        self.instructions.get_buffer().set_text(
            "Very long (1200 char) string snipped.")
        #pack pane 1
        self.inst_window.add(self.instructions)
        self.inst_align.add(self.inst_window)
        self.main.pack1(self.inst_align, True, False)
        # build right side components
        self.opt_align = gtk.Alignment(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.opt_buttons = gtk.VButtonBox()
        self.opt_buttons.set_layout(gtk.BUTTONBOX_START)
        self.opt_buttons.set_homogeneous(True)
        self.opt_0 = gtk.RadioButton(
            None,
            "Label 0",
            True)
        self.opt_1 = gtk.RadioButton(
            self.opt_0,
            "Label 1",
            True)
        self.opt_2 = gtk.RadioButton(
            self.opt_0,
            "Label 2",
            True)
        self.opt_3 = gtk.RadioButton(
            self.opt_0,
            "label 3",
            True)
        self.opt_4 = gtk.RadioButton(
            self.opt_0,
            "Label 4",
            True)
        self.opt_5 = gtk.RadioButton(
            self.opt_0,
            "Label 5",
            True)
        self.doit_box = gtk.HButtonBox()
        self.doit = gtk.Button("Do It !", None, True)
        self.doit.expand = False
        self.doit.fill = False
        self.doit.set_alignment(0.5, 0.0)
        # Put the buttons in the box and while were at it, bind their
        # released, and pressed options
        for i in range(0, 6):
            s = "self.opt_" + str(i)
            self.opt_buttons.pack_start( eval(s), True, False, 0 )
            s1 = s + '.connect("released", self._emit_signal, i)'
            s2 = s + '.connect("pressed", self._emit_signal, i)'
            exec(s1)
            exec(s2)

        self.doit_box.pack_start(self.doit, True, False, 0)
        self.opt_buttons.pack_start(self.doit_box, True, False, 0)
        self.opt_align.add(self.opt_buttons)
        self.main.pack2(self.opt_align, True, False)

        self.top.show_all()




gobject.type_register(Source)
gobject.signal_new('choice_changed',
                   Source,
                   gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
                   gobject.TYPE_NONE, (Source, gobject.TYPE_INT))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def cb_test(widget, event, value):
        print "widget is", widget
        print "Value is ", value
        return

    test = Source()
    win = gtk.Window()
    win.add(test.top)
    win.show_all()
    test.connect('choice_changed', cb_test)
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: The window is too small. If you set a fitting size to the window (a width like 800), it works.

Comment: @elya54 - realized that about 40 minutes ago.  The code wasn't the error, the test was.  If you put that in as an answer ill accept it and eat my humble pie for stupid question of the day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a window with greater than the position of the HPane divider. Here is a stripped down example:

```
import gtk

class Source(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Source, self).__init__()
        label1 = gtk.Label("The first label")
        label2 = gtk.Label("The second label")

        paned = gtk.HPaned()
        paned.add1(label1)
        paned.add2(label2)
        paned.set_position(600)

        self.add(paned)
        self.set_size_request(800, 400)  # needs sufficient width here
        self.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Source()
    gtk.main()
```